# extjs record destroy by desired property

Tags: javascript, ajax, extjs, grid, record

I'm developing Exjs mvc application.
I have an Extjs model :

```
Ext.define('JC.model.File', {
   extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
   fields: [
       {name: 'id', type: 'int'},
       {name: 'fileName', type: 'string'},
       {name: 'fileSize', type: 'string'},
       {name: 'position', type: 'string'}
   ]
});
```

and a store:

```
Ext.define('JC.store.Files', {
   extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
   model: 'JC.model.File',
   proxy: {
       url: JC.Util.createUrl('upload/getfiles'),
       type: 'ajax',
       simpleSortMode: true,
       reader: {
           type: 'json',
           root: 'items',
           totalProperty: 'totalCount'
       },
       api: {
           create: '',
           read: undefined,
           update: undefined,
           destroy: JC.Util.createUrl('upload/deletefile')
       },

       actionMethods:{create: 'POST', read: 'GET', update: 'POST', destroy: 'GET'}
   }
});
```

and a grid panel with the following columns:

```
columns: [
    {header: 'id', dataIndex: 'id', flex: 1},
    {header: 'file name', dataIndex: 'fileName', flex: 1},
    {header: 'file size', dataIndex: 'fileSize', flex: 1},
    {header: 'position', dataIndex: 'position', flex: 1}, {
        xtype: 'actioncolumn', items: [
            {
                icon: 'css/images/tree/black-trash-16.png', // Use a URL in the icon config
                tooltip: 'Delete',
                handler: function(grid, rowIndex, colIndex) {
                    var rec = grid.getStore().getAt(rowIndex);
                    grid.getStore().destroy(rec);
                }
            }
        ]
    }
],
```

at the line:

```
 grid.getStore().destroy(rec);
```

an ajax request is created as below:

```
http://localhost:8084/myserver/deletefile?_dc=1422789950411&id=JC.model.File-6
```

I want the id requested for delete operation be my desired property of record i,e `rec.id` and I want it to be `int` type.I want the request to be something like this:

```
http://localhost:8084/myserver/deletefile?_dc=1422789950411&id=6
```

How can I do that?

Comment: That's a good question. I never observed the behavior you have. ExtJs always sent the idProperty value, i.e. id as int. What is causing that different behavior in your case ?

Comment: A first thing, that might not be related : use POST as method. GET requests should not change the data.

Comment: I have not seen that style of config for a store. I have used `proxy{type: rest}` before. http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.Rest

Comment: Do you mean `api` config of proxy ? see http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.Rest-cfg-api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have setup a [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/hfi) to replicate the issue.

I only managed to get this working by changing the actionMethod for the destory action to POST and setting an idProperty on the model.

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function() {
        Ext.define('File', {
            extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
            idProperty: 'id',

            fields: [{
                name: 'id',
                type: 'int'
            }, {
                name: 'fileName',
                type: 'string'
            }, {
                name: 'fileSize',
                type: 'string'
            }, {
                name: 'position',
                type: 'string'
            }]
        });

        Ext.define('Files', {
            extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
            model: 'File',
            autoLoad: true,
            proxy: {
                url: 'data1.json',
                type: 'ajax',
                simpleSortMode: true,
                reader: {
                    type: 'json',
                    rootProperty: 'items',
                    totalProperty: 'totalCount'
                },
                api: {
                    create: '',
                    read: 'data1.json',
                    update: '',
                    destroy: 'delete.json',
                },

                actionMethods: {
                    create: 'POST',
                    read: 'GET',
                    update: 'POST',
                    destroy: 'POST'
                }
            }
        });

        var store = Ext.create('Files');

        Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
            title: 'Test',
            store: store,
            columns: [{
                header: 'id',
                dataIndex: 'id',
                flex: 1
            }, {
                header: 'file name',
                dataIndex: 'fileName',
                flex: 1
            }, {
                header: 'file size',
                dataIndex: 'fileSize',
                flex: 1
            }, {
                header: 'position',
                dataIndex: 'position',
                flex: 1
            }, {
                xtype: 'actioncolumn',
                items: [{
                    icon: 'css/images/tree/black-trash-16.png',
                    tooltip: 'Delete',
                    width:50,
                    handler: function(grid, rowIndex, colIndex) {
                        var rec = grid.getStore().getAt(rowIndex);
                        rec.erase();
                    }
                }]
            }],
            height: 300,
            width: 600,
            renderTo: Ext.getBody()
        });
    }
});

// Sample JSON Data
{
    "success": true,
    "totalCount": 5,
    "items": [{
        "id": 1,
        "fileName": 'file1.png',
        "fileSize": 93204,
        "position": 1
    }, {
        "id": 2,
        "fileName": 'file2.png',
        "fileSize": 93204,
        "position": 1
    }, {
        "id": 3,
        "fileName": 'file3.png',
        "fileSize": 93204,
        "position": 1
    }, {
        "id": 4,
        "fileName": 'file4.png',
        "fileSize": 93204,
        "position": 1
    }, {
        "id": 5,
        "fileName": 'file5.png',
        "fileSize": 93204,
        "position": 1
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but you can send the model data that you wish by defining the proxy.writer in the model, in the proxy writer definition you can define the transform.fn which returns the data to send to the server as the model.data:

```
writer: {
        type: 'json',
        allDataOptions:  {changes: true, critical: true},
        partialDataOptions: {changes: true, critical: true},
        encode: true,
        rootProperty: 'group',
        transform: {
            fn: function(data, request, isDraft, model) {
                if(request) {
                    if(request.getAction() == 'destroy') {
                        data.id = me.get('id');
                        data.type = me.get('type');
                    }else if(request.getAction() == 'create') {
                        delete(data.id);
                    }
                }
                return data;
            }
        }
    },
```